# CSS not showing on live website

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I don't know what happen but what's the usual reason why CSS won't work in IE7? My previous works are fine in IE7.

On my localhost, I tested it and it works. Now when it goes live and added some php codes by my partner the CSS is not showing. When the website loads it just plain white, like a notepad with text. Eventhough the  tag for the CSS is there. Any answers to this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide your code and/or a link to the site in question? Your question is vary vague with details.

Comment: Yes I use Firebug to test it and also I use Development Tool of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that you don't have any absolute paths?
If your CSS path was `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/localsite/style.css">` then it won't work live.

Also check the `<base href="...">` tag if you have one, and check that it is set properly for the live site.

Comment: Thank you!, its the <base> tag